# Prevent an action in a controller within a rails engine from executing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-engines

To prevent an action from executing in some controller in a rails app unless authenticated you could use

```
before_filter :validate_user, :only => [:create, :update]
```

This would prevent create and update from being executed unless an authorized user was attempting it. If the actions create and update are in a controller within a rails engine this does not work.

How do you conditionally block the execution of an action on a controller that is within a rails engine?

Answer (score 0):

If the `validate_user` method in question returns `false`, the filter chain is halted and the action will not be performed.

The typical pattern looks like this:

```
def validate_user
  unless (...valid_conditions...)
     flash[:error] = "You're not logged in."
     redirect_to(login_path)
     return false
   end
end
```

You can do whatever you want before halting the filter chain, but ideally you `redirect` or `render` something first.

Comment: Thanks for your reply tadman. The problem is that the actions I want to block are within an engine and the engine controllers don't inherit from the application controller in the main application. The only solution I have found is to override the application_controller in the engine namespace with your own implementation which inherits from your main application controller. This feels wrong to me but then again I am a long time functional programmer and my OO senses are not all the keen so lots of things feel wrong to me. I would love some commentary on this.

Comment: You can always make a module that defines this validation and force the main ApplicationController to `include` it. It's not always a good idea to monkey patch things like this but sometimes it is the only way.